# Angular 8 Unit Test, Cannot set property 'valueAccessor' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to simply **pass the test** *(should create - component=> toBeTruthy)* for the custom component (angular component class) implemented with **ControlValueAccessor**. I've injected NgControl in `constructor` and pass the `this` keyword.

```
 constructor(@Optional() @Self() public controlDir?: NgControl) {
    this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }
```

And  then on ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
    const control = this.controlDir.control;
    const validators = control.validator ? [control.validator] : [];
    const asyncValidators = control.asyncValidator ? [control.asyncValidator] : [];

    control.setValidators(validators);
    control.setAsyncValidators(asyncValidators);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

In the test file

```
describe('TextInputComponent', () => {
  let component: TextInputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TextInputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TextInputComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TextInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

And the errors

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'valueAccessor' of null

I'd be appreciated if anyone shares your ideas to solve this issue?

Thank you.
Rabin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931778/how-to-unit-test-a-reactive-component-where-ngcontrol-is-decorated-with-self See if that helps.

Comment: It was slightly helping though and figure it out. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solved this issue by creating the new mock class component with calling the `<app-text-input formControlName="test"></app-text-input>` template including form.

Here is a code details:

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
   <app-text-input formControlName="input">
   </app-text-input>
  </form>`
})
class TestingInput {
  @ViewChild(TextInputComponent, { static: true })
  textInputComponent: TextInputComponent;

  form = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl('Test Value')
  });
}

describe('TextInputComponent', () => {
  let component: TextInputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestingInput>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TextInputComponent, TestingInput],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestingInput);
    component = fixture.componentInstance.textInputComponent;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Thanks, Everyone for the answer and comments, all did not solve the exact issue though at least got the idea to figure out. 
**Feel free to post the answer if you have any other better way to solve this issue**. 
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock class NgControl for  like this :

```
export class TestNgControl {
 valueAccessor : any = null;
}
```

Then in the providers for configureTestingModule method, you can write something like this :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TextInputComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers : [{ provide : NgControl, useClass : TestNgControl}]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Please let me know if this works or not.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I've tried it but still showing the  **Cannot set property 'valueAccessor' of null**

Comment: Can you please console.log(this.controlDir.valueAccessor) in the constructor itself?
To check if it is null or not. I am not able to reproduce the issue due to setup but I tried injecting same inside my component and it shows controlDir itself a null.

Comment: Yeah, it's getting null. That's why getting an error I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding the @Optional decorator for controlDir, then wrapping the assignment of this to controlDir.valueAccessor in an if statement, since controlDir won't be assigned in the test.

```
  constructor(@Self() @Optional() public controlDir: NgControl) {
    if (controlDir) {
      controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }
```

Then in your ngOnInit() you also need to wrap any calls to access controlDir in an if statement since it won't be set.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.controlDir) {
      const control = this.controlDir.control;
      const validators = control.validator
        ? [control.validator, this.validate]
        : this.validate;
      control.setValidators(validators);
      control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
```

Some folks have had issues building for prod with the above, and have also solved your problem using the directions at the URL below, which is using TestbedStatic.overrideComponent in the test.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31632

Comment: Jason, This looks better! I had the @Optional decorator though had not it wrap by if statement in both places (constructor and ngOnInit). I'd go with this solution in the future anyway and recommend it to all as well. Thanks for the effort.